# How to make a user select an image and save the image as a variable?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to create a VB.net form where the user can click on a button and it is associated with a specific image and when the user clicks the image and then clicks select it will add it to a variable.

If you need more information please let me know ([this is the image of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beOxs.jpg))

I wanted to know:

- how to assign an image to a button ( so when you click it, it means that the user wants that image) I am not sure if my method is correct
- how to assign the image that was selected to a variable (so that once the variable is called it will output the image)
- and how to end the form once the image is selected. (once use clicks the select button it should end the form, or if the user clicks cancel it should end the form).

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Property SelectedPictureBox() As Image

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Controls.OfType(Of ButtonPictureBox).ToList().ForEach(
             Sub(box)
                 AddHandler box.Click, AddressOf AllButton_Click
             End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AllButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        SelectedPictureBox = CType(sender, ButtonPictureBox).PictureBox
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetBtnSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetBtnSelect.Click
        If SelectedPictureBox IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show(SelectedPictureBox.Name)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an image")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnTropicalFloral_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnTropicalFloral.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxTropicalFloral.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnLightGeode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLightGeode.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxLightGeode.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnStripes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnStripes.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxStripes.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnAuroraBorealis_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAuroraBorealis.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxAuroraBorealis.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDiagonals_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDiagonals.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxDiagonals.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnComb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnComb.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxComb.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnMountain_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnMountain.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxMountain.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnLandscape_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLandscape.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxLandscape.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnGradient_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGradient.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxGradient.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnAbstract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAbstract.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxAbstract.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnGeode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGeode.Click
        SelectedPictureBox = PictureBoxGeode.Image
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I think you might be heading down the wrong path a little.  I would look at creating a custom control that had the image and button in it, then it's a very simple task to work the relationship between the button and associated picture box

Comment: @Hursey could you give me a sample of what it may look like, I am having a hard time trying to do that

Comment: That I don't think I could do in an answer, there is a fair amount of concepts to cover off there.  I would recommend some reading on creating user controls first.  For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-simple-data-binding?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

My VB is a bit rusty, so I'll have to give the answer in C#. I'm sure you'll get the gist, and will be able to translate it into VB.

First of all: whenever you see that you are repeating things, for instance by copy-paste, you should stop, and rethink your design: maybe it would be better to create a method for this, or an object.

All your PictureBox/Button combinations have some common behavior. This means that you should think of creating a class for it.

In your case, you have the combination of a Button and a PictureBox. You want to be able to set and get an Image. The PictureBox will show this image. Finally you want to be notified if the operator clicks the Button.

In the event handler of this Notification you want to know which pictureBox/Button combination sent the event. You get the image from this combination and close the form.

In WinForms, whenever you want to have a class that is a combination of several controls, you make a `UserControl`.

In Visual Studio, in the solution control, right click on the project (not the solution!) and select: Add new Item. Select to add a new User Control. Think of a proper name, I'll call this `ImageSelectionControl`

Use the visual studio designer to give ImageSelectionControl the proper size. Add a PictureBox and a Button. Also use the visual studio designer to add an EventHandler for if the operator clicks the button.

In the code of the User Control add the property to Set / Get an Image. The Image that you set will be displayed in the PictureBox; the Image that you get is the image that is displayed in the PictureBox.

Here comes the first chunk of C#:

```
public Image Image
{
    get => this.pictureBox1.Image;
    set => this.pictureBox1.Image = value;
}
```

I think in VB this will be very similar.

Now you want that users of your control (= software, not humanoids) get notified that the operator selects an image. Officially, you even want to hide how the operator selected this image: all you want to say: "Hey, the operator selected my image!"

Normally you would do this using an event:

The 2nd piece of C#:

```
public event EventHandler ImageSelected;
```

The event won't have any data. It will only say: "Hey, the operator selected my image!". The event event handler will have to find out which user control raised the event, and fetch the image.

Ok, raise the event:

```
private void OnImageSelected()
{
    this.ImageSelected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

It will be a bit more difficult to translate this into VB. What it does, it checks if there is at least one person who wants my events. If so it raises the event. with two parameters: the sender (which is me), and no parameters. Later we will see how the receiver of the event works.

Finally: if the operator clicks the button, he indicates that he wants to select the image in the user control, and thus OnImageSelected needs to be called

```
private void ButtonSelect_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnImageSelected();
}
```

We've finished creating the UserControl. After Compilation you will find it in visual studio designer toolbox.

So we'll go to the form that will have to display the eleven PictureBox-Button combinations. Let's call this form: `ImageSelectionForm`.

Using Visual Studio Designer, add 11 ImageSelectionControls. If you know already at design time which control will show which image, you can do this in the designer, similarly to how you set the text or the background of a button.

If you only know at run-time which control should show which image, consider to add a method, for instance if you want to load it from file:

```
void ShowImage(ImageSelectionControl imageSelectionControl, string imageFileName)
{
    Image image = this.LoadImageFromFile(imageFileName);
    this.imageSelectionControl.Image = image;
}
```

Or maybe you have a different method to decide which ImageSelectionControl should displaye which image. I guess you get the gist.

Almost done. ImageSelectionForm needs to be notified about the selected image, so just like you would do with a button, you need to subscribe to event ImageSelected.

In the constructor or ImageSelectionForm, subscribe to the events:

```
private ImageSelectionForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // subscribe to events
    this.controlBlueGeod.ImageSelected += this.ImageSelected;
    this.controlAbstract.ImageSelected += this.ImageSelected;
    ...
}
```

Of course, you can put all ImageSelectionControls in one list and use foreach to subscribe (that is too much VB for me, no idea how to do this)

The event handler:

```
void ImageSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // we know that the sender is the one that holds the selected images:
    ImageSelectionControl imageSelectionControl = (ImageSelectionControl)sender;
```

We will be closiing the form very soon, so we will have to remember this selected image somewhere in a property:

```
public Image SelectedImage {get; set;}
```

So continuing the event handler:

```
    this.SelectedImage = imageSelectionControl.Image;
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

So the selected image is saved. The dialog result is set to indicate that an image was selected, not cancel clicked. And the form is closed.

### Showing the form and process the selected image

The form that has to show ImageSelectionForm has a procedure:

```
private void ShowImageSelectionForm()
{
    using (ImageSelectionForm dialog = new ImageSelectionForm())
    {
         // show the dialog and process the result:
         DialogResult dlgResult = dialog.ShowDialog(this);

         if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             this.ProcessSelectedImage(dialog.SelectedImage);
         }
         else
         {
             // TODO: process cancel 
         }
    }
}
```

There is one memory leak: if you created a lot of images, all images need to be Disposed after usage. Best is to by overriding `Component.Dispos(bool)`

ImageSelectionControl:

```
protected override Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && this.Image != null)
    {
        this.Image.Dispose();
    }
}
```

ImageSelectionForm:

```
protected override Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        this.controlBlueGeod.Dispose();
        this.controlAbstract.Dispose();
        ...
    }    ​
```

​}

This is quite a nuisance for 11 controls. Therefore quite often a Form or a UserControl has a `System.ComponentModel.IContainer components`. If you add your ImageSelectionControls to this container, then the ImageSelectionControls will be automatically disposed when ImageSelectionForm is disposed.

​

Answer (score 0):

You have two Controls that work together to allow users to preview and select one or more Images in the UI. When you have this kind of scenario, build a UserControl that contains all the required UI elements and the logic used perform this action.

To build this UserControl:

- Open the Project menu and select `Add User Control...`
- Right away, set (in this order):

  - `AutoScaleMode = Dpi`
  - `Font = Segoe UI, 9pt`
  - `BackColor = Color.Transparent`
  - Set a `Size` that you think is the minimum required to show an Image and a Button
  - When you have found the *right* size, set also the `MinimumSize` to this value
- Add a Button to the UC, configure it as needed, set its `Width` as the Width of the UC minus 4 pixels. Position the Button at the bottom of UC, 2 pixels to the left and set `Anchor = Bottom, Left, Right`
- Add a PictureBox, same `Width` and `Left` location as the Button. Set the `Height` as required, then `Anchor = Top, Bottom, Left, Right`

Design completed. Build the Project.

Now, your UserControl needs to provide means to set an Image to the PictureBox and the Text of the Button.

- You can add two Public Properties of Type `Image` and `String` that, when a value is assigned, set the `PicureBox.Image` property and the `Button.Text` property.

Also, when the Button is clicked, the UserControl needs to notify that the User has performed a selection, so whatever other code needs to do something with this information, will be able to act on it.

- In an event-driven UI, you make your UC raise a public event that interested parties can subscribed to, to receive a notification that *something happened*.

You just need to define a Field of Type `Event` and give it a name. In this case, e.g.:

```
Public Event ImageSelection As EventHandler
```

When the Button is clicked, you raise the event:

```
RaiseEvent ImageSelection(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
```

The sample UserControl is named `ImagePicker`, the PictureBox is named `picImage` and the Button is `btnSelectImage`

```
Public Class ImagePicker

    Public Event ImageSelection As EventHandler
    Private m_Picture As Image = Nothing
    Private m_Title As String

    Public Property Picture As Image
        Get
            Return m_Picture
        End Get
        Set
            m_Picture = Value
            picImage.Image = m_Picture
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Title As String
        Get
            Return m_Title
        End Get
        Set
            m_Title = Value
            btnSelectImage.Text = m_Title
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub btnSelectImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectImage.Click
        RaiseEvent ImageSelection(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub
End Sub
```

In your Form (for example), you can the subscribe to this event to receive a notification that the User has selected the Image of one of your UserControls.

- When the event is raised, the `sender` object is the UserControl that raised the event. You can then cast `sender` to your UserControl Type and read the Public Property that references the Image you have assigned to it.

In a Form, you can add some of your UserControls to a FlowLayoutPanel (in the example, named `flpPreviews`), which will take care of the layout of these Controls.

While adding the UserControls, you set their Public Properties and also subscribe to the Public event.
When the event is raised, cast `sender` to `ImagePicker` and read its public `Picture` property to get the reference of the Image selected:

```
Public Class SomeForm

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add three ImagePicker UserControls to a FlowLayoutPanel
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            Dim picker = New ImagePicker()
            picker.Picture = [Some Image]
            picker.Title = "Some Title"
            ' Subscribe to the event
            AddHandler picker.ImageSelection, AddressOf ImageSelectionChanged
            flpPreviews.Controls.Add(picker)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Property SelectedImage As Image

    Private Sub ImageSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        SelectedImage = DirectCast(sender, ImagePicker).Picture
        ' Show the selected Image in a PictureBox, child of the Form
        picSelected.Image = SelectedImage
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: UserControl ImagePicker]